# Is it possible to get phone number via Google oAuth2?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

According to OpenID specification it should be possible  http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-properties-list-1_0-01.html however there is no mention of it in Google OAuth2 Documentation. Anyone have experience with that?

Comment: Did you got any alternative solution?

Answer (score 9):

We don't currently offer the phone number as part of our people/get Google+ API.

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people

Visibility of attributes in this api are controlled by the user in G+ profile settings.

The userinfo api is specific to OpenId and probably won't get this field.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall

It may happen in the future and we're open to requests.

davep

Comment: Is there any direct way to request it? It is a feature that makes a lot of sense in certain type of location aware applications (such as ours). And not enabling to use phone number creates additional step for users to complete the process. If there is a way to contact you directly (such as email) I would gladly discuss this issue.

Comment: @David Primmer :: now can we get uer phone number via Google api?

Comment: @Vijaysinh Parmar how to get phone number via google api? can you give any reference links for it

Comment: I also asked same in above comment