# Is it possible to get phone number with Google plus API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

After I get successful authentication, I've already got user information by below method.

```
// 1. Create a |GTLQuery| object to get people  profile who are authenticated

GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

// 2. Execute the query.

[[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLPlusPerson *gpUser,NSError *error) {
// here I've retrieved all info about users
    NSLog(@"GP user first name : %@",gpUser.name.givenName);
    NSLog(@"GP user last name : %@",gpUser.name.familyName);
    //But don't know how extract phone number. 
}];
```

[This google doc](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people) shows how to retrieve info via google api. But couldn't see how to **extract phone number** if user make it visible as public? **Is it possible with google plus api?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get phone number via Google oAuth2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276919/is-it-possible-to-get-phone-number-via-google-oauth2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google does not offer access to this data using their G+ API, even though the user marked the information as "public".

See [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279993/145997) from 2012 where it's clearly stated that phone numbers are not available through G+ API.

Comment: Ya, I agree with those link which you provided. But they conclude this  because google doc doesn't provide to get access with phone number. But My question is "Is there any other `query` or `scope` to get this"? If not means, where could find that statement "You couldn't get user info with phone number even you marked as public"?

Comment: Usually, when the official documentation does not provide a way to get something you're looking for, it means it is not supported by the provider (i.e. Google). The available scopes for G+ are described here: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/scopes - nothing more than what you've already seen. If the phone numbers you are looking for are always public, you can always try to write your own code to grab them from the public G+ profile, but of course this is going to be trickier...